# Where to put the redirect code for mobile devices in Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, mobile

I got the detection code for C# from http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/. Now, I don't know where to put this up and how to get it working.

Basically, all I want is that my mobile visitors should be redirected to http://m.site.com, where my mobile website resides. Let me know how to achieve this task via above code or any other method.

**NOTE**:- The main website is an Asp.net MVC3 application.

Comment: is your mobile site a separate application from your main mvc3 app ?

Comment: yes its completely separate application. I am not using areas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would call the code in the global.asax Application_BeginRequest event.

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string u = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
    if (BrowserDetect.IsMobile(u)) //Pretend there is class and function that has all the regex stuff here.
    {
        Response.Redirect("http://m.site.com");
    }
}
```

Comment: seems good....BTW for any changes in global.asax, do i need to redeploy the MyApp.dll and MyApp.pdb ?? Or just overwriting the Global.asax file ensure the changes are applied ?

Comment: I believe you'll have to recompile the application for the changes to take effect in asp.net mvc.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can write an asp.net [HTTP Module](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307996) in your main mvc3 app. In the module handle the BeginRequest event and put your detection code in there. If it's a mobile request then redirect.